# Mysql Select GROUP BY with value greater than 1

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

Hi I want to **GROUP BY** file_serial but only when **file_serial > 1** that mean no duplicate file_serial with value bigger than 1

[image: Current Table]

so it should look like

[image: Wanted Table]

Any idea how, would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: So, you're just getting the first value for a given `file_serial` when it is greater than 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be

```
select * from table
where  file_serial > 1
group by file_title
having count(*) > 1

UNION

select * from table
```

**UPDATE**

The above will work only if all the selecting columns with the same value. In this case you may need to change as since file_id is different for the same title.

```
    select * from table
    where  file_serial > 1
    group by file_title
    having count(*) > 0 

    UNION

    select * from table
    file_serial <= 1
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/686c2/14)**

Comment: Hi Abhik Chakraborty, I see that you **group by file_title** but my file_title isn't duplicate as in your demo it always differents :(

Comment: In that case you can change the group by file_title to file_serial

Comment: I still can't figure it out how to order by `file_id DESC` if I add another column with bigger ID and the same `file_serial` it only show me the smaller ID
[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01b2d2/10/0)

Comment: Thanks @Abhik Chakraborty Here is my updated about this question.
It's working. [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48723/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48723/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try below query, where no need of extra having clause-

```
SELECT 
file_id,file_title,file_serial 
FROM mytable 
WHERE file_serial<=1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
file_id,file_title,file_serial 
FROM mytable 
WHERE file_serial>1 
GROUP BY file_serial;
```